# unsupported_grant_type error when requesting a token

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to request and token from an api. below is my code

```
$login = 'TES001';
$password = 'AA758';
$url = "thetestapisite.com/Ticket/v1/Auth/Token";
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

$postData = array(
            'grant_type'=> 'password',
            'username'=> $login,
            'password'=> $password,
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: theworkingkey"));       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
var_dump($response);
```

In the api doc it says the grant_type should be password and the Content type in header should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. but when i run the code it give me the below error

```
array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(22) "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

can some one tell me what am i doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: cURL generates a `multipart/formdata` request, when you pass an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS - and simply pretending otherwise via the Content-Type header is probably not changing how it creates the request body. Try and pass your parameters in URL-encoded string format, you can use `http_build_query` on your parameter array to create it.

Comment: @CBroe i changed it to    `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));` and its giving `{ "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error"}` error now

Comment: Can you link to the documentation, please?